# Using templates with C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a red black tree using templates. The insert function takes two generic types, Item and Key. However, when I'm creating an instance of the RedBlackTree in the main() and calling the function 'InsertKey', the program gives the error: Method 'InsertKey' could not be resolved. Also, I don't know what to pass as arguments in the 'InsertKey' function. I implemented an array which consists of random elements. The array should be one of the parameters, but I can't figure out what is the other parameter.

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef REDBLACKTREE_H_
#define REDBLACKTREE_H_

template <class Item, class Key>
class RedBlackTree
{
    typedef enum
    {
        BLACK,
        RED
    }ColourNode;

    /* user data stored in tree */
    typedef struct {
        int data;
    } treedata;

    typedef struct RBT
    {
        struct RBT *left;
        struct RBT *right;
        struct RBT *parent;
        struct RBT *root;
        ColourNode colour;
        //Item item;
        Key key;
        treedata data;
    }RBTNode;

    public:
        ~RedBlackTree(); // destructor
        RedBlackTree(Item, Key); // default constructor

        void InsertKey(const Item *&, const Key *&);
        void FixingInsert(const Item *&, const Key *&);
        int RemoveKey(Item, Key);
        int FindKey(Item, Key);

    //private:
        //RedBlackTree<Item, Key> *rootPointer;

};

#endif /* REDBLACKTREE_H_ */
```

This is my main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "RedBlackTree.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    const int arraysize = 200;
    int arr[arraysize];

    RedBlackTree<int, int> t1(int, int);

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i <= arraysize-1;  i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 210;
        //printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= arraysize-1;  i++)
    {
        t1.InsertKey(arr[i], // something else//); //InsertKey should have another parameter, but for now I am trying to figure out why it cannot be resolved. 
    }

}
```

Also, any ideas of what the something else could be please? I can't figure out what to pass.

Comment: The typedefs are unnecessary. Just define, for example, `struct tree data { int data; };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RedBlackTree<int, int> t1(int, int);
```

Here you are declaring a function called `t1` that returns a `RedBlackTree<int, int>` and takes two arguments both of type `int`.

I think you actually want to create a `RedBlackTree<int, int>` object and call it `t1`. It has one constructor, that takes an `Item` and a `Key`. However, you've commented it as saying it's a *default* constructor, which it isn't. A default constructor is one that takes no arguments. I think you meant to declare the constructor like so:

```
RedBlackTree(); // default constructor
```

Then you can create an object of this type like so:

```
RedBlackTree<int, int> t1;
```

You never *pass* types between normal parantheses like `(int, int)`. They always go between the angle brackets, like `<int, int>` and after a template name. In this case, the template name is `RedBlackTree` and we want to instantiate it with `int` types, so we do `RedBlackTree<int, int>`. There's nothing to pass to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have an idea of what I can pass as another argument in the InsertKey function as I can't figure out what to pass in order to add elements in the red black tree?

Answer (score 1):

`RedBlackTree<int, int> t1(int, int);` is being treated as a function declaration. You haven't defined a default constructor for your `RedBlackTree`, so you must either provide one, or construct your object with arguments.

```
RedBlackTree() {  }
```

The next problem is your function signature for `InsertKey` expects two arguments, when you're only giving it one.

```
void InsertKey(const Item *&, const Key *&);
t1.InsertKey(arr[i], /* something else must go here */)
```

As well as that, you're passing an `int` when your function expects an `int *&`. If you meant to pass these arguments by const-reference, remove the asterisk.

```
void InsertKey(const Item &, const Key &);
```

Otherwise, you need to pass a pointer.

```
t1.InsertKey(&arr[i], /* something else */);
```

The problem is that it expects a `const` pointer, so you would have to do something like this:

```
const int* pointer = &arr[i];
t1.InsertKey(pointer, /* something else */);
```

Comment: That's neither a vexing parse nor a most vexing parse. It's just a straight up function declaration.

Comment: @sftrabbit OK I removed that part from the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions of what something else could be please as I can't figure out what to pass in order to add elements in a red black tree?

Answer (score 0):

You promised the user a function `InsertKey()` which takes two pointers. You tried to call `InsertKey()` with one value instead. That's not going to fly.

As a general recommendation, make sure your data structure works with concrete type before turning it into a template (it is the other way around for algorithms). I'd also recommend that you `RedBlackTree<K, V>` travels in terms of `K` and `V` objects rather than using pointers. If a use really wants to use pointer, the class template could be used by specifying pointer arguments.